# Multiple Queries, show result in same div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

When clicking "Popular", how to replace  contents with result from new query (getPopular)?

( v-for="casino in allCasinos"  needs to instead show: v-for="casino in getPopular" )

```
<div @click="activate(1); getPopular();">Popular</div>
<div @click="activate(2); getNew();">New</div>

<div id="list" v-for="casino in allCasinos" :key="casino.name">
  <div v-if="$apollo.loading">Loading...</div>
  <div>{{ casino.name}}</div>
</div>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
methods: {
  activate:function(el){
      this.active_el = el;
  },
},
apollo: {
  allCasinos: gql`{
    allCasinos(limit: 6) {
      name,
    }
  }`,
  getPopular: gql`{
    getPopular(limit: 6) {
      name,
    }
  }`,
  getNew gql`{
    getNew(limit: 6) {
      name,
    }
  }`,
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, there is no reason to use separate queries - use one common query with `filter` (beside `limit`) parameter.

---

**UPDATE**

```
casinos: gql`query casinos($filter: String!) {
    casinos(filter: $filter, limit: 6) {
        name
    }
}`,
```

Comment: How would you be passing the value from clicked choice/div to the dynamic filter of query?

Comment: By standard graphql variables - docs: https://akryum.github.io/vue-apollo/guide/apollo/queries.html#reactive-parameters

Comment: Rather `filter: $filter` and type def in query.  Prepare api, test with `graphiql`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time ... I just tried the following: https://dpaste.de/KXBL  but unfortunately it results in, ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in GraceApiWeb.CasinoResolver.all_casinos/2 . Do you know why?

Comment: I prefer react and don't work with elixir ;) Probably there shoud be `arg: filter, :string` ... and you don't have a function/method `list_casinos` aware of two args?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a local data property, `casinos`, that stores the current set of casinos you want to display. And you could set the value of `casinos` in each of your `click` handlers. Finally you could use `casinos` instead of `allCasinos` in your `v-for`:

```
<div @click="activate(1); casinos = getPopular();">Popular</div>
<div @click="activate(2); casinos = getNew();">New</div>

<div id="list" v-for="casino in casinos" :key="casino.name">
  <div v-if="$apollo.loading">Loading...</div>
  <div>{{ casino.name}}</div>
</div>

<script>
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
data: function () {
  return {
    casinos: this.allCasinos
  }
},
```

Comment: Interesting and I think this is the way to go, but how would I connect the result of each query to "casinos" ?

"And you could set the value of casinos in each of your click" How does this look like?

Thank you for your time

Comment: See the first line of code in my answer. It includes `casinos = getPopular()`

Comment: This way can look like an easier one but definitively not `the right way` neither `apollo/graphql way`. Just imagine another requirements, f.e. sorting order, search, another filters. Looks easy but increasing client complexity (and suitable only for small datasets) vs just next query parameters.